# Fix two-finger Trackpad Scrolling on a Macbook running Bootcamp

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, macbook-pro, boot-camp, touchpad

This is an issue that's annoyed me for some time. About a year ago, the two-finger scrolling in Windows 7 on my Macbook Pro stopped working. I discovered that a fix for this is to open Bootcamp from the control panel, go to the Trackpad tab, tick and untick "Tap to click" and click ok. This has to be done every time the machine is woken from sleep or rebooted. I'm now using Windows 8 and encountering the same issue.

I've tried several different driver revisions, and none have helped. I'm sick of going through the motions. Has anyone got a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a great solution, but you could use AutoHotKey (or any other scripting language) to automatically check and uncheck the box every time you boot.  Very hacky, but better than nothing.

Comment: I'm a big fan of autohotkey, and I thought about using it if I could figure out a command to run. Otherwise I'd have to just open the control panel, type "boo" to select bootcamp, and enter to launch. That's REALLY hacky. I don't like that solution as it would stop me doing anything with the UI until it was done. I know it would only take a second or two but there's a good chance something else could open at the same time (if its running at startup) and screw everything up

Comment: You can have AutoHotKey send keystrokes to a particular window, rather than the active one.  That way, you do not need to worry about other windows opening.  I agree that it is not a great solution, but if nobody else knows how to fix it properly (if it even is possible; it sounds like this is just a bug), AutoHotKey is better than doing it manually every time.

Comment: Agreed. I'm currently looking into using Devcon to maybe disable and re-enable the trackpad though. If I can get that to work it would be a better solution. I'll try it and post the results